# Undeclared type - using C struct in Swift by bridging header

Tags: ios, c, swift

I have already seen other questions related with this, but nothing helped me. I have a problem integrating ImageMagick sdk into swift.

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var wand: MagickWand!
    // [...]
}
```

The error:

```
Error: Use of undeclared type 'MagickWand'
```

I correctly imported MagicWand.h in Briding Header.

```
#ifndef Header_h
#define Header_h
#import "MagickWand.h"
#endif
```

In MagickWand.h, the struct is defined correctly.

```
typedef struct _MagickWand MagickWand;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `_MacickWand` work?

Comment: @Alexander No, it doesn't work.

Comment: Do any other types from `MagickWand.h` work?

Comment: The functions in h file appear from Intellisense. But not this struct.

Comment: Hmmm that's odd.

Comment: Your snippet there doesn't look like a bridging header. I would add a super simple Objective C class to your Swift project and first verify that your bridging header is set up correctly by referencing that Objective C class from one of your Swift classes.

Comment: @DaveWeston Actually there are more lines in bridging header and I am already using objective-c class in swift.

Comment: If I import `MagickWand.h` in objective-c class, I can use MagicWand there.

Comment: Remove the `#ifndef Header_h` guard. That shouldn't be in the bridging header.

Comment: @Fury How did you solve the issue? Faced the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Incomplete struct definitions like that are imported as `OpaquePointer` (that's basically what `OpaquePointer` was made for). If Swift actually has access to the contents of the `MagickWand` struct, then it can import it as a named type.

Comment: Which is kind of a funny, as it leads to weaker typing than C does offer. In C, `MagickWand *` is not just any pointer, it must be a pointer to memory of type `struct _MagickWand`, no matter what that types looks like (unknown as not defined). `OpaquePointer` however is a pointer to anything, there is no type constraint anymore. In C,  pointers to incomplete srtucts are not interchangeable without an explicit cast.