# How to access Objective-C typedef from Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, typedef, bridging-header

I'm trying to access an Objective-C `typedef struct` inside the framework from the Swift via bridging header but it returns error that `MagickWand cannot find in scope`.

```
typedef struct _MagickWand
  MagickWand;
```

Is there a way to access `typedef` from the code of Swift?
[image]

Comment: `MagickWand` is an “incomplete type” and those are not imported to Swift, compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/43365067/1187415 for a similar issue. More concrete advice might be possible if you show *how* you want to use that type – perhaps call C functions taking an `MagickWand *` argument?

Comment: @MartinR Yes actually I need that type to use their function as a parameter. Question updated.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42685508/1187415